# Is it possible to override Hibernate's 'like' operator in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm wondering if the following is feasible in Hibernate ; when writing an HQL query, you can say things like

```
select foo from Foo where foo.barString like "%baz%"
```

This works assuming that class Foo has a String attribute called barString.

Now, assume that Foo as a bar attribute of type Bar, but that Bar has a well-known, canonical String representation. Assume that this is something that can easily and quickly computed (say, by concatenation), but that it is *not* stored in the DB. Is there a way to map / modify the class so that you can write something like either

```
 select foo from Foo where foo.bar like "%baz%"
```

or

```
 select foo from Foo where foo.bar.toCanonicalString like "%baz%"
```

or even

```
 select foo from Foo where toCanonicalString(foo.bar) like "%baz%"
```

?

Thanks
PH

Comment: The thing is HQL is used to run queries on DB, not java objects themselves. So it has to be translated to SQL somehow, how would you translate some generic java method to SQL? I would say you must represent `toCanonicalString ` in SQL, something like `from Foo where CONCAT(foo.bar, foo.something) like "%baz%"`. And if it cannot be translated into SQL then Hibernate wouldn't be able to do it automatically either.

Comment: Sure, I was looking for a way to do the translation at the HQL level, if possible. (In the end, obviously, I'll have to explain the function to HQL)

Comment: You can remap hql functions to generate different sql, e.g. registerFunction( "substring", new SQLFunctionTemplate( Hibernate.STRING, "substring(?1, ?2, ?3)" ) ); but I don't think you can manipulate the properties before they get converted to sql.

Comment: @phtrivier wont your bar object contain a string field in it? If it does why dont you use `where foo.bar.stringField like "%baz%"`

Comment: @NaveenBabu no, my object does not necessarily have a string field that represent it. If I remember correctly I was dealing with phone numbers ; I was storing them with the country code, trunk and significant part in different columns, but I wanted to do a search from user-entered version of the number. So If I had three columns with 33, 0,  and 6xyz, most users would like to type "+336xyz" or "06xyz", or maybe just "6xy" to find the number. And so I had to do the concatenation (and other transforms).

Answer (score 1):

for your problem you could use formula in the mapping 
with xml:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column

with annotations:
http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e2009

and that is it you have a calculated field in your hql